# How to mock AuthSession in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, mock, apexmock

I want to cover this method :

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void  endUserSession(Id userId){
    List<AuthSession> uSessions = [ select Id , UsersId FROM  AuthSession  WHERE  UsersId =:userId AND  IsCurrent = TRUE ];
    if (!uSessions.isEmpty()) {
        delete uSessions;
    }
}
```

Since we can not create AuthSession in test class , I need to mock it and to mock it I create an interface :

```
public interface IDatabaseWrapper {
    List<SObject> queryWithBinds(
        String queryString,
        Map<String, Object> bindMap,
        System.AccessLevel accessLevel
    );
}
```

and class that implement the interface :

```
public without sharing class DatabaseWrapper implements IDatabaseWrapper {
    public List<SObject> queryWithBinds(
        String queryString,
        Map<String, Object> bindMap,
        System.AccessLevel accessLevel
    ) {
        return Database.queryWithBinds(queryString, bindMap, accessLevel);
    }
}
```

and here's how I modified my main method :

```
@TestVisible
private static IDatabaseWrapper db = new DatabaseWrapper();

@AuraEnabled
public static void  endUserSession(Id userId){
    List<AuthSession> uSessions = db.queryWithBinds(
        'select Id , UsersId FROM  AuthSession  WHERE  UsersId =:userId AND  IsCurrent = TRUE',
        new Map<String, Object>{
            'userId' => userId
        },
        System.AccessLevel.USER_MODE
    );
    if (!uSessions.isEmpty()) {
        delete uSessions;
    }
}
```

But i'm blocked on how to create its test method , how to inject a mock implementation of IDatabaseWrapper

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using whole words for variable names. That caveat aside, you simply need to assign a new value to `db`. You need to define a mock type first, either in your given test class or, if it has wide utility, in a separate top level mock. An example of the latter is included below.

```
@IsTest
public class MyDatabaseMock implements IDatabaseWrapper
{
    final List<SObject> records;
    public MyDatabaseMock(List<SObject> records) { this.records = records; }
    public List<SObject> queryWithBinds(
        String queryString, Map<String, Object> bindMap, AccessLevel accessLevel
    ){
        return records;
    }
}
```

You can add more nuance, but that's the basic idea. Then in your test, simply add this line before executing your method. You have to build `mockRecords` in memory first.

```
MyClass.db = new MyDatabaseMock(mockRecords);
```

Comment: I was able to cover my method by using : 

`ApcFooterController.endUserSession(Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession().get('UsersId'));
    List<AuthSession> sessionsAfterDelete = [SELECT Id FROM AuthSession WHERE UsersId = :testUser.Id];
    System.assertEquals(0, sessionsAfterDelete.size(), 'AuthSessions should be deleted');` 

I didn't understand how to create MockRecords for AuthSession ..

Comment: You should be able to just construct them in memory. `AuthSession session = new AuthSession(/*fields*/);`

Comment: i couldn't , its read only object .. i showed you the "temporary solution"

Comment: Generally the other option is to construct a `Map<String, Object>`, serialize it, then deserialize back out into the type you need.